# Apache tiles using spring mvc

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I have a comment tile i want refresh just the comment added not all comment 
my code is :

```
<definition name="accueil" extends="new.definition">
     <put-attribute name="showAllPub" value="/WEB-INF/pages/showAllPub.jsp"/>
     <put-attribute name="tileCommentPub" value="/WEB-INF/pages/allPub/tileCommentPub.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

Can I concatenate the name TileCommentpub with `-${p.commentId}`
to refresh just the comment added?
If yes how I can pass comment id to tiles.xml?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I concatenate the name TileCommentpub with -${p.commentId}

Unfortunately not; the tile is just a fixed template created at deploy time, and you probably don't know the comment ID until run-time.

Perhaps this will help; put your comment into `tileCommentPub.jsp`;

```
.... your existing comment jsp code ....
<p>Comment ID is : ${p.commentId}</p>
<p>For example : ${comment.text}</p>
```

And inject the comment specific data from your controller;

```
@RequestMapping
public String getSomePageWithComment (final Model model) {
    // ... get the comments...
    model.addAttribute("comment", comment);
    model.addAttribute("p", p);
    return "tileCommentPub";
}
```